# 404 Not Found After updating all URL in database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to transfer my word press application from a development server onto a production server . I have successfully re uploaded all the contents from the development server onto the production and also restored the MySQL Database . Along with the transfer , I'm hosting the application on a new domain .

I also ran this command to update all the URL in the original database

```
 UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldsite.com', 'http://www.newsite.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
 UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldsite.com','http://www.newsite.com');
 UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldsite.com', 'http://www.newsite.com');
 UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://www.oldsite.com', 'http://www.newsite.com');
```

The problem is , the main page www.newsite.com is working but the related pages isn't displaying , I get the error message Not Found . www.newsite.com/community

```
Not Found

 The requested URL /what-we-do/ was not found on this server.
 Apache/2.2.29 (Amazon) Server at  Port 80
```

Comment: Do you have rewrite module enable on the new server?

Comment: @Abel nope , Can u post a solution please

Comment: depends on your server, but if you Debian or Ubuntu:  `apt-get install mod-rewrite`  then `a2enmod rewrite` , then `/etc/init.d/apache2 reload`

Comment: Do you change the permalink settings

Comment: Nope  , Can u elaborate on answer ? @Shan

Comment: If you diddnt do anything on permalinks,then it may not be the problem.Normally when change permalink, and then when tranfer to another server cause this problem.Do one thing.Change the settings>permalink to default.then save it.Again change to postname. save it.hope it solves the problem

Comment: @Shan, sorry I posted similar answer before I saw your comment. No need to change anything in the permalink options by the way, just save will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Admin/Permalinks and simply Save them again (No need to make any changes).

Answer (score 0):

So your whole site is supported by Wordpress or you just use Wordpress manage part of your site ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Linux server you are supposed to do something like [this](http://www.dev-metal.com/enable-mod_rewrite-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) or [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite). For RPM based OS based [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-wordpress-on-centos-7) might help

If it's a Windows based well depends on the server, for instance in wamp is just to enable the mod_rewrite in Apache, and change the Apache rewrite option like in the Linux manual.

If you tell me the OS I can probably give more server specific info.

Comment: This is the site linuxadmins.be . The main page is working but when u click on the pages . Its not working . Do you reckon its the Mysql database?

Comment: Post the apache logs. normaly at the end of the files /var/logs/apache2/error.log and access.log. They normaly give information about why your webs are denied.

Comment: Amazon Linux AMI 2014.09.2 (HVM) . I had to do yum install mod-rewrite

Comment: I have edited the answer... check out the how to for your kind of OS. If you can post the apache logs like I said on the last post.

Comment: This is the looks like the error log, it seems fine, so your apache2 it's ok. Post the access log to see what happens with the requests to the server

Comment: It does not show the logs of when you access a page. You are just supposed to show me the last part of the file. This logs are from some moment that you were installing plugins and that stuff. Access a page a few times where you get the errors. Then go to the file and the copy only the last part of the file. Where Apache handles the requests that fail.

Comment: My logs ain't updating for some reason sudo cat /var/log/httpd/access_log .

Comment: check if the http user has rights on the folder. it needs to be able to write. make it the owner.